# Split a unicode string into components containing numbers and letters

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to split the string `u'123K` into `123` and `K`. I've tried `re.match("u'123K", "\d+")` to match the number and `re.match("u'123K", "K")` to match the letter but they don't work. What is a Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: If the string will always be some amount of numbers followed by one letter you can use `nums, letter = string[:-1], string[-1]`

Comment: for `re.match`, the pattern is supposed to go first, then the string you're evaluating. you have it backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall()` to find all numbers and characters:

```
>>> s = u'123K'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[a-zA-Z]+', s) # or use r'\d+|\D+' as mentioned in comment in order to match all numbers and non-numbers.
['123', 'K']
```

If you are just dealing with this string or if you only want to split the string from the last character you can simply use a indexing:

```
num, charracter = s[:-1], s[-1:]
```

Comment: `r'\d+|\D+'` is  shorter. However, specs are not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) method, grouping digits:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> for _,v in it.groupby(s, key=str.isdigit):
        print(''.join(v))


123
K
```